# SHA 512 Password with webapp2 and App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

If you are using webapp2 with Google App Engine you can see there is only one way to create an user with the "create_user" method [auth/models.py line:364]

But that method call to "security.generate_password_hash" method where in not possible use SHA 512

Q1: I would like to know what is the best way to create a SHA 512 Password with webapp2 and App Engine Python?

Q2: Is good idea use SHA 512 instead of encryption offered by webapp2 (SHA1), or it's enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observe, the default User model doesn't provide any way to customize the hash function being used. You could subclass it and redefine the problematic methods to take a hash parameter, or file a feature request with the webapp2 project.

Webapp2's password hashing has much bigger issues, though, as it doesn't do password stretching. While it optionally(!) salts the hash, it doesn't iterate it, making brute force attacks more practical than they should be for an attacker. It should implement a proper password primitive such as PBKDF2, SCrypt, or BCrypt.

To answer your question about relative strengths of hash functions, while SHA1 is showing some weakness, nobody has successfully generated a collision, much less a preimage. Further, the HMAC construction can result in secure HMACs even with a hash function that's weak against collision attacks; arguably even MD5 would work here.

Of course, attacks only ever get better, never worse, so it's a good idea to prepare for the future. If you're concerned about security, though, you should be much more concerned about the lack of stretching than the choice of hash function. And if you're *really* concerned about security, you shouldn't be doing authentication yourself - you should be using the Users API or OAuth, so someone else can have the job of securely storing passwords.

Comment: Thanks Nick, due to I'm doing a Boilerplate to promote App Engine showing how to create own accounts (users without yahoo, google, linkedin, twitter, facebook, etc) and also login with third parties website (OAuth) I should be doing authentication myself. BTW good answer and I'll subclass it. 

This is the project http://appengine.protoboard.cl 

Good luck at Smart Sparrow

Comment: There's a counter-balance to Nick's otherwise fine advice: First, passwords fall most often to dictionary attacks against weak passwords, and social engineering. Brute-forcing SHA1s is way, way down the list of things you need to worry about. Second, mechanisms you add yourself raise the risk of introducing other bugs.